# ERROR: While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES) Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /path/to/my/ruby global/wrappers/cert

Tags: ruby, macos, openssl, rvm

```
`rvm upgrade 2.2.1 2.2.3`
```

fails here

```
+ gem wrappers regenerate
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /Users/snowcrash/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@global/wrappers/cert
+ return 1
Making gemset ruby-2.2.3@global pristine........................................................................................
Error running '__rvm_with ruby-2.2.3@global gemset_pristine',
showing last 15 lines of /Users/snowcrash/.rvm/log/1449848326/gemset.pristine-ruby-2.2.3@global.log
+ _failed+=("${_gem} --version ${_version}")
+ read _gem _version _platforms
+ ((  29 > 0  ))
+ rvm_error '\n'\''command gem pristine --extensions cert --version 1.2.7 coderay --version 1.1.0 commander --version 4.3.5 deliver --version 1.6.4 dotenv --version 2.0.2 fastlane --version 1.47.0 frameit --version 2.4.0 gem-wrappers --version 1.2.7 gym --version 1.2.0 krausefx-shenzhen --version 0.14.6 launchy --version 2.4.3 match --version 0.1.0 pem --version 1.1.0 pilot --version 1.1.0 produce --version 1.1.0 pry --version 0.10.3 rouge --version 1.10.1 scan --version 0.3.2 sentry-raven --version 0.15.2 sigh --version 1.2.1 snapshot --version 1.4.1 spaceship --version 0.16.0 supply --version 0.2.2 terminal-notifier --version 1.6.3 unf_ext --version 0.0.7.1 xcode-install --version 1.0.1 xcodeproj --version 0.28.2 xcpretty --version 0.2.1 xcpretty-travis-formatter --version 0.0.4'\'' failed, you need to fix this gems manually.'
+ rvm_pretty_print stderr
+ case "${rvm_pretty_print_flag:=auto}" in
+ case "${TERM:-dumb}" in
+ case "$1" in
+ [[ -t 2 ]]
+ return 1
+ printf %b '\n'\''command gem pristine --extensions cert --version 1.2.7 coderay --version 1.1.0 commander --version 4.3.5 deliver --version 1.6.4 dotenv --version 2.0.2 fastlane --version 1.47.0 frameit --version 2.4.0 gem-wrappers --version 1.2.7 gym --version 1.2.0 krausefx-shenzhen --version 0.14.6 launchy --version 2.4.3 match --version 0.1.0 pem --version 1.1.0 pilot --version 1.1.0 produce --version 1.1.0 pry --version 0.10.3 rouge --version 1.10.1 scan --version 0.3.2 sentry-raven --version 0.15.2 sigh --version 1.2.1 snapshot --version 1.4.1 spaceship --version 0.16.0 supply --version 0.2.2 terminal-notifier --version 1.6.3 unf_ext --version 0.0.7.1 xcode-install --version 1.0.1 xcodeproj --version 0.28.2 xcpretty --version 0.2.1 xcpretty-travis-formatter --version 0.0.4'\'' failed, you need to fix this gems manually.\n'
```

The permissions seem wrong on this:

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  staff  343 Dec 11 09:49 /Users/snowcrash/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@global/wrappers/cert
```

I assume I need to change these permissions but, checking other files in that directory, it seems I'll need to change other permissions too.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

For me it was rbenv so :

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /Users/$(whoami)/.rbenv
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the example for rbenv, for me it wasn't this obvious.

Answer (score 4):

Probably you installed RVM or Ruby using sudo into your home folder. You should own the files by yourself. Take them over with

`sudo chown -R $(whoami) /Users/$(whoami)/.rvm`